# Cleanest way of validating AWS credentials in the code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

During the application startup, I want to check if my AWS credentials are valid before I try to run any other AWS request (such as SNS, SQS and S3 requests).

What's the cleanest way of doing this?

Even the simplest operations such as getting the list of policies requires having the policy `iam:ListPolicies`, is there a very simple request that doesn't require any policies at all?

Comment: Possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36026996/4072843

Answer (score 0):

I validate AWS credentials by making a simple describe api call to some methods.
like describeVolumes(), describeLoadBalancers() or describeAddresses()...

Comment: you need certain policies to do that

Comment: @cahen You will see AuthFailure in one case, UnauthorizedOperation in the other.