# AWS validating Credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services

Say I get a set of access keys from a user,
Is there a way to validate them?

For now I'm making simple API calls to methods like,
describeVolumes(), describeLoadBalancers() or describeAddresses()
and work with Exception codes to validate the Credentials.

But what if I don't know the service?
Is there a better way to validate the Credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the AWS IAM API, specifically the [GetUser function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html).
From the description:

> Retrieves information about the specified user, including the user's
>   creation date, path, unique ID, and ARN.
>
> If you do not specify a user name, IAM determines the user name
>   implicitly based on the AWS access key ID used to sign the request.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wish to validate whether the **Credentials** are "correct", then your current method is good:

- Make a request to AWS
- Examine the return code
- If the response is `InvalidAccessKeyId` then the credentials are invalid

This is different to checking whether the user has **Permissions** to make the API call. Determining whether they have the correct permissions could be done using the [IAM Policy Simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?#) or by attempting a call and checking the response (eg `AccessDenied`).